# In app purchase receipt verification in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

We are following the raywenderlinch tutorial from http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation

But there are some error which I am getting when import verificationController classes in our project. Right now, I am using iOS8.

```
Error is: Implicit declaration of function 'checkReciptSecurity' is invalid in C99
```

I have also search for sample code of Verification class on apple developer site ,Their page is not found.

Please give me your view to solve this or provide the link of verification classes which are update to iOS8.

Answer (score 3):

In VerificationController.h put the function prototype like this :

```
- (void)verifyPurchase:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction completionHandler:(VerifyCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
BOOL checkReceiptSecurity(NSString *purchase_info_string, NSString *signature_string, CFDateRef purchaseDate);
```

The reason of doing this is the line number calling the function **checkReceiptSecurity** is before the declaration of function.

You have to modified the VerificationController.m file code.
I have put the modified code here.

```
#import "VerificationController.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"

static VerificationController *singleton;

@implementation VerificationController {
    NSMutableDictionary * _completionHandlers;
}

+ (VerificationController *)sharedInstance
{
    if (singleton == nil)
    {
        singleton = [[VerificationController alloc] init];
    }
 return singleton;
}


 - (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _completionHandlers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}


- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromPlistData:(NSData *)data
{
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                                           options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                            format:nil
                                                                             error:&error];
if (!dictionaryParsed)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing plist");
    }
    return nil;
}
return dictionaryParsed;
}


- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromJSONData:(NSData *)data
{
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:0
                                                                   error:&error];
if (!dictionaryParsed)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing dictionary");
    }
    return nil;
}
return dictionaryParsed;
}


#pragma mark Receipt Verification

// This method should be called once a transaction gets to the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased or    SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored state
// Call it with the SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt
- (void)verifyPurchase:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction completionHandler:(VerifyCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{    
BOOL isOk = [self isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:transaction];
if (!isOk)
{
    // There was something wrong with the transaction we got back, so no need to call verifyReceipt.
    NSLog(@"Invalid transacion");
    completionHandler(FALSE);
    return;
}

// The transaction looks ok, so start the verify process.

// Encode the receiptData for the itms receipt verification POST request.
NSString *jsonObjectString = [self encodeBase64:(uint8_t *)transaction.transactionReceipt.bytes
                                         length:transaction.transactionReceipt.length];

// Create the POST request payload.
NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"receipt-data\" : \"%@\", \"password\" : \"%@\"}",
                     jsonObjectString, ITC_CONTENT_PROVIDER_SHARED_SECRET];

NSData *payloadData = [payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

#warning Check for the correct itms verify receipt URL
// Use ITMS_SANDBOX_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL while testing against the sandbox.
NSString *serverURL = ITMS_SANDBOX_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL; //ITMS_PROD_VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL;

// Create the POST request to the server.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:payloadData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

_completionHandlers[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:conn]] = completionHandler;

[conn start];

// The transation receipt has not been validated yet.  That is done from the NSURLConnection callback.
}

// Check the validity of the receipt.  If it checks out then also ensure the transaction is something
// we haven't seen before and then decode and save the purchaseInfo from the receipt for later receipt validation.
- (BOOL)isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
if (!(transaction && transaction.transactionReceipt && [transaction.transactionReceipt length] > 0))
{
    // Transaction is not valid.
    return NO;
}

// Pull the purchase-info out of the transaction receipt, decode it, and save it for later so
// it can be cross checked with the verifyReceipt.
NSDictionary *receiptDict       = [self dictionaryFromPlistData:transaction.transactionReceipt];
NSString *transactionPurchaseInfo = [receiptDict objectForKey:@"purchase-info"];
NSString *decodedPurchaseInfo   = [self decodeBase64:transactionPurchaseInfo length:nil];
NSDictionary *purchaseInfoDict  = [self dictionaryFromPlistData:[decodedPurchaseInfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *transactionId         = [purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"transaction-id"];
NSString *purchaseDateString    = [purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"purchase-date"];
NSString *signature             = [receiptDict objectForKey:@"signature"];

// Convert the string into a date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *purchaseDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[purchaseDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Etc/" withString:@""]];


if (![self isTransactionIdUnique:transactionId])
{
    // We've seen this transaction before.
    // Had [transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary objectForKey:transactionId]
    // Got purchaseInfoDict
    return NO;
}

// Check the authenticity of the receipt response/signature etc.

BOOL result = checkReceiptSecurity(transactionPurchaseInfo, signature,
                                   (__bridge CFDateRef)(purchaseDate));

if (!result)
{
    return NO;
}

// Ensure the transaction itself is legit
if (![self doTransactionDetailsMatchPurchaseInfo:transaction withPurchaseInfo:purchaseInfoDict])
{
    return NO;
}

// Make a note of the fact that we've seen the transaction id already
[self saveTransactionId:transactionId];

// Save the transaction receipt's purchaseInfo in the transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary.
[transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary setObject:purchaseInfoDict forKey:transactionId];

return YES;
}

// Make sure the transaction details actually match the purchase info
- (BOOL)doTransactionDetailsMatchPurchaseInfo:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction withPurchaseInfo:(NSDictionary *)purchaseInfoDict

{
if (!transaction || !purchaseInfoDict)
{
    return NO;
}

int failCount = 0;

if (![transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"product-id"]])
{

    failCount++;
}

if (transaction.payment.quantity != [[purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"quantity"] intValue])
{
    failCount++;
}

if (![transaction.transactionIdentifier isEqualToString:[purchaseInfoDict objectForKey:@"transaction-id"]])
{
    failCount++;
}

// Optionally check the bid and bvrs match this app's current bundle ID and bundle version.
// Optionally check the requestData.
// Optionally check the dates.

if (failCount != 0)
{
    return NO;
}

// The transaction and its signed content seem ok.
return YES;
}



- (BOOL)isTransactionIdUnique:(NSString *)transactionId
{
NSString *transactionDictionary = KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY;
// Save the transactionId to the standardUserDefaults so we can check against that later
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];

if (![defaults objectForKey:transactionDictionary])
{
    [defaults setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:transactionDictionary];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

if (![[defaults objectForKey:transactionDictionary] objectForKey:transactionId])
{
    return YES;
}
// The transaction already exists in the defaults.
return NO;
}


- (void)saveTransactionId:(NSString *)transactionId
{
// Save the transactionId to the standardUserDefaults so we can check against that later
// If dictionary exists already then retrieve it and add new transactionID
// Regardless save transactionID to dictionary which gets saved to NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *transactionDictionary = KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                                   [defaults objectForKey:transactionDictionary]];
if (!dictionary)
{
    dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], transactionId, nil];
} else {
    [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:transactionId];
}
[defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:transactionDictionary];
[defaults synchronize];

}


- (BOOL)doesTransactionInfoMatchReceipt:(NSString*) receiptString
{
// Convert the responseString into a dictionary and pull out the receipt data.
NSDictionary *verifiedReceiptDictionary = [self dictionaryFromJSONData:[receiptString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Check the status of the verifyReceipt call
id status = [verifiedReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
if (!status)
{
    return NO;
}
int verifyReceiptStatus = [status integerValue];
// 21006 = This receipt is valid but the subscription has expired.
if (0 != verifyReceiptStatus && 21006 != verifyReceiptStatus)
{
    return NO;
}

// The receipt is valid, so checked the receipt specifics now.

NSDictionary *verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary  = [verifiedReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"receipt"];
NSString *verifiedReceiptUniqueIdentifier       = [verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"unique_identifier"];
NSString *transactionIdFromVerifiedReceipt      = [verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"transaction_id"];

// Get the transaction's receipt data from the transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary
NSDictionary *purchaseInfoFromTransaction = [transactionsReceiptStorageDictionary objectForKey:transactionIdFromVerifiedReceipt];

if (!purchaseInfoFromTransaction)
{
    // We didn't find a receipt for this transaction.
    return NO;
}


// NOTE: Instead of counting errors you could just return early.
int failCount = 0;

// Verify all the receipt specifics to ensure everything matches up as expected
if (![[verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"bid"]
      isEqualToString:[purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"bid"]])
{
    failCount++;
}

if (![[verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"product_id"]
      isEqualToString:[purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"product-id"]])
{
    failCount++;
}

if (![[verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"quantity"]
      isEqualToString:[purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"quantity"]])
{
    failCount++;
}

if (![[verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"item_id"]
      isEqualToString:[purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"item-id"]])
{
    failCount++;
}

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"identifierForVendor")]) // iOS 6?
{
#if IS_IOS6_AWARE
    // iOS 6 (or later)
    NSString *localIdentifier                   = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSString *purchaseInfoUniqueVendorId        = [purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"unique-vendor-identifier"];
    NSString *verifiedReceiptVendorIdentifier   = [verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"unique_vendor_identifier"];


    if(verifiedReceiptVendorIdentifier)
    {
        if (![purchaseInfoUniqueVendorId isEqualToString:verifiedReceiptVendorIdentifier]
            || ![purchaseInfoUniqueVendorId isEqualToString:localIdentifier])
        {
            // Comment this line out to test in the Simulator.
            failCount++;
        }
    }
#endif
} else {
    // Pre iOS 6 
//        NSString *localIdentifier           = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
//        NSString *purchaseInfoUniqueId      = [purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"unique-identifier"];
//        if (![purchaseInfoUniqueId isEqualToString:verifiedReceiptUniqueIdentifier]
//            || ![purchaseInfoUniqueId isEqualToString:localIdentifier])
//        {
//            // Comment this line out to test in the Simulator.
//            failCount++;
//        }        
}


// Do addition time checks for the transaction and receipt.

if(failCount != 0)
{
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}


#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegate (for the verifyReceipt connection)

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Connection failure: %@", error);

VerifyCompletionHandler completionHandler = _completionHandlers[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
[_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
completionHandler(FALSE);

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

BOOL isOk = [self doesTransactionInfoMatchReceipt:responseString];

VerifyCompletionHandler completionHandler = _completionHandlers[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
[_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:connection]];
if (isOk)
{
    //Validation suceeded. Unlock content here.
    NSLog(@"Validation successful");
    completionHandler(TRUE);

} else {
    NSLog(@"Validation failed");
    completionHandler(FALSE);
}
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
if ([[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    SecTrustRef trust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL didUseCredential = NO;
    BOOL isTrusted = [self validateTrust:trust error:&error];
    if (isTrusted)
    {
        NSURLCredential *trust_credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
        if (trust_credential)
        {
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:trust_credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            didUseCredential = YES;
        }
    }
    if (!didUseCredential)
    {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
} else {
    [[challenge sender] performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
}

// NOTE: These are needed for 4.x (as willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: is not supported)
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
return [[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
if ([[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
    SecTrustRef trust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL didUseCredential = NO;
    BOOL isTrusted = [self validateTrust:trust error:&error];
    if (isTrusted)
    {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
        if (credential)
        {
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            didUseCredential = YES;
        }
    }
    if (! didUseCredential) {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
} else {
    [[challenge sender] performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark NSURLConnection - Trust validation

- (BOOL)validateTrust:(SecTrustRef)trust error:(NSError **)error
{

// Include some Security framework SPIs
extern CFStringRef kSecTrustInfoExtendedValidationKey;
extern CFDictionaryRef SecTrustCopyInfo(SecTrustRef trust);

BOOL trusted = NO;
SecTrustResultType trust_result;
if ((noErr == SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trust_result)) && (trust_result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified))
{
    NSDictionary *trust_info = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)SecTrustCopyInfo(trust);
    id hasEV = [trust_info objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kSecTrustInfoExtendedValidationKey];
    trusted =  [hasEV isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]] && [hasEV boolValue];
}

if (trust)
{
    if (!trusted && error)
    {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kSecTrustError" code:(NSInteger)trust_result userInfo:nil];
    }
    return trusted;
}
return NO;
}
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Base 64 encoding

- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:input length:length];
return [data base64EncodedString];
}
- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
NSData * data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:input];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size) {
size_t outputLength;
return NewBase64Encode(buf, size, NO, &outputLength);
}
void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{
 return NewBase64Decode(s, strlen(s), data_len);
}
@end
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Check Receipt signature
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#include <Security/Security.h>
#include <AssertMacros.h>
unsigned int iTS_intermediate_der_len = 1039;

unsigned char iTS_intermediate_der[] = {
put the hexacode here
};

BOOL checkReceiptSecurity(NSString *purchase_info_string, NSString *signature_string, CFDateRef purchaseDate)
{
BOOL valid = NO;
SecCertificateRef leaf = NULL, intermediate = NULL;
SecTrustRef trust = NULL;
SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

NSData *certificate_data;
NSArray *anchors;

/*
 Parse inputs:
 purchase_info_string and signature_string are base64 encoded JSON blobs that need to
 be decoded.
 */

require([purchase_info_string canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] &&
        [signature_string canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], outLabel);

size_t purchase_info_length;
uint8_t *purchase_info_bytes = base64_decode([purchase_info_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                                             &purchase_info_length);

size_t signature_length;
uint8_t *signature_bytes = base64_decode([signature_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                                         &signature_length);

require(purchase_info_bytes && signature_bytes, outLabel);

/*
 Binary format looks as follows:

 RECEIPTVERSION | SIGNATURE | CERTIFICATE SIZE | CERTIFICATE
 1 byte           128         4 bytes
 big endian

 Extract version, signature and certificate(s).
 Check receipt version == 2.
 Sanity check that signature is 128 bytes.
 Sanity check certificate size <= remaining payload data.
 */

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct signature_blob {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t signature[128];
    uint32_t cert_len;
    uint8_t certificate[];
} *signature_blob_ptr = (struct signature_blob *)signature_bytes;
#pragma pack(pop)
uint32_t certificate_len;

/*
 Make sure the signature blob is long enough to safely extract the version and
 cert_len fields, then perform a sanity check on the fields.
 */
require(signature_length > offsetof(struct signature_blob, certificate), outLabel);
require(signature_blob_ptr->version == 2, outLabel);
certificate_len = ntohl(signature_blob_ptr->cert_len);

require(signature_length - offsetof(struct signature_blob, certificate) >= certificate_len, outLabel);

/*
 Validate certificate chains back to valid receipt signer; policy approximation for now
 set intermediate as a trust anchor; current intermediate lapses in 2016.
 */

certificate_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:signature_blob_ptr->certificate length:certificate_len];
require(leaf = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certificate_data), outLabel);

certificate_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:iTS_intermediate_der length:iTS_intermediate_der_len];
require(intermediate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certificate_data), outLabel);

anchors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)intermediate];
require(anchors, outLabel);

require_noerr(SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(leaf, policy, &trust), outLabel);
require_noerr(SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, (__bridge CFArrayRef) anchors), outLabel);

if (purchaseDate)
{
    require_noerr(SecTrustSetVerifyDate(trust, purchaseDate), outLabel);
}

SecTrustResultType trust_result;
require_noerr(SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trust_result), outLabel);
require(trust_result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified, outLabel);

require(2 == SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust), outLabel);

/*
 Chain is valid, use leaf key to verify signature on receipt by
 calculating SHA1(version|purchaseInfo)
 */

CC_SHA1_CTX sha1_ctx;
uint8_t to_be_verified_data[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_SHA1_Init(&sha1_ctx);
CC_SHA1_Update(&sha1_ctx, &signature_blob_ptr->version, sizeof(signature_blob_ptr->version));
CC_SHA1_Update(&sha1_ctx, purchase_info_bytes, purchase_info_length);
CC_SHA1_Final(to_be_verified_data, &sha1_ctx);

SecKeyRef receipt_signing_key = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);
require(receipt_signing_key, outLabel);
require_noerr(SecKeyRawVerify(receipt_signing_key, kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1,
                              to_be_verified_data, sizeof(to_be_verified_data),
                              signature_blob_ptr->signature, sizeof(signature_blob_ptr->signature)),
              outLabel);

/*
 Optional:  Verify that the receipt certificate has the 1.2.840.113635.100.6.5.1 Null OID

 The signature is a 1024-bit RSA signature.
 */

valid = YES;

outLabel:
if (leaf) CFRelease(leaf);
if (intermediate) CFRelease(intermediate);
if (trust) CFRelease(trust);
if (policy) CFRelease(policy);

return valid;
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a memory leak from the SecTrustCopyPublicKey function - receipt_signing_key is never CFRelease'd. I think in the  outLabel: it needs an if (receipt_signing_key) CFRelease(receipt_signing_key); and then receipt_signing_key needs to be declared and set to NULL at the beginning of the function before the require statements to fix this issue. I know this comes originally from Apple's source code so this leak may be in many places.

Comment: If I could up-vote this 100 times I would!! I accidentally deleted my target and had to re-create it which saw me having issues with VerificationController!  Re-ordering it as you suggested did the trick. Thank you!