# XCode 6 verificationController.m issues

Tags: ios, ios8, in-app-purchase, xcode6

I am using VerificationController.m provided by [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation) for validating receipts for in ap purchase. It is working fine for XCode5 but in XCode6 it is giving number of errors. probably due to C++ code like:

- Missing Code for Method declaration
- @end must appear in objective-c
- context Conflicting types for 'checkReiptSecurity'

  can anyone tell me what is needed to be done ?

Edit : Here are errors screenshot
[image: Errors]

[image: Errors]

[image]

Comment: Could you include the actual errors?

Comment: Have you added NSData+Base64.m and NSData+Base64.h files in that folder in witch VerificationController.m is present. ? if your project has already NSData+Base64 files then make separate folders for them

Comment: I have the same issue, I solved it by modified the method sequence. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890349/in-app-purchase-receipt-verification-in-ios8/26891519#26891519) is my answer. Do you find out any other solution of it ?

Comment: Hey Nimisha , I have modified my code as per your instruction now and Its works for me in new XCode 6.3 . Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Have you fixed this? I was running in to the exact same problem so I'll leave my fix here for anyone that comes looking. It turns out in newer versions of Xcode you aren't allowed to put C/C++ code in objective-C context anymore. So I moved the declarations for `unsigned int iTS_intermediate_der_len`, `unsigned char iTS_intermediate_der[]`, `char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)`, and `void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)` to the top of the file, above the `@implementation` tag.

Comment: you saved my day... thanx +1

Comment: Yes, thank you!!!  One tip for anyone who needs it: the order of those pieces matters, so if you move them all to the top, be sure the `import` statements are at the very top above them, and try shuffling their orders until it works.  Took some tries, but I finally got it working!

Answer (score -2):

Have you downloaded sample code? I have downloaded sample code and its working fine at my side. It seems that you have missed or added an extra braket `} or {` in your code.

May be this happened when you was trying to comment this code `[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;` because originally this line produce an error.

Comment: can u give me the link of sample code? code I am using was working fine in xcode 5

Comment: @Haris I am talking about raywenderlich sample code... you can download it from 

http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/downloads/InAppRagePart2Finished.zip

if you face error then comment above given lines

Comment: This project is free of errors, but after adding to my project, still same issues.

Comment: Have you added NSData+Base64.m and NSData+Base64.h files in that folder in witch VerificationController.m is present. ?
if your project has already NSData+Base64 files then make separate folders for them.