# Validate and Verify In-App purchase Non-Renewable iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, xcode7, non-renewing-subscription

Third time apple rejected the binary due to In-App purchase type. Am app using IAP to **subscribe the package for 1Month, 1Year and Free**. Earlier I used Consumable so, app rejected and suggested to use **"Non-Renewable"**. Am following the tutorial "https://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial". I have downloaded the "VerificationController" class files from the tutorial to verify the transaction. But, am getting many errors,

```
VerificationViewController.m
No visible @interface for 'VerificationController' declares the selector 'encodeBase64:length:'
No visible @interface for 'VerificationController' declares the selector 'decodeBase64:length:'
Implicit declaration of function 'checkReceiptSecurity' is invalid in C99
Conflicting types for 'checkReceiptSecurity'
Missing context for method declaration

CommonDigest.
Missing '@end'
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this and submit the app today?

Comment: Hi @Yuvaraj.M did u find the solution for it?Even i m getting the same issue

Comment: Hi @pooja_1205 I didn't find the solution and after that we dropped the IAP integration. If you find the solution for this issue please share your answer here. That could be helpful for everyone. If I get the solution I will share it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this with tkdkop answer on this thread : [XCode 6 verificationController.m issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382041/xcode-6-verificationcontroller-m-issues). Hope this can help and save some time to others.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my idea on this: 
First of all, Non-renewable subscription is the most tricky to handle in all subscriptions. Its up to developer to handle:

1. Subscription expiration date
2. Tracking subscription
3. Not to mention you have to provide restore button, so that users can restore their purchases

Here is how I handled mine:
I use combination of iCloud and backend server to track important data.

1. Whenever user subscribes to non renewable (i.e purchases it), I store
   purchase date, and create expiration date equivalent to one month
   from purchase date in backend server and in iCloud . Note my subscriptions were for one month only. In iCloud store `storeUserPurchase.set(key: nrs_key, vale: someData)`
2. Whenever a subscribed user want to access material subscribed to, I check if the expiration date based on some unique id stored in
   user's iCloud, using this unique id, I ask my server to compute the
   expiration date based on this id. If hasn't expired then give access
   to material. Something like

   `purchaseInfo = getSomePurchaseDataFor(key: nrs_key)
   serverValidateReceiptAndGetExpirationDateFor(receipt, purchaseInfo)`
3. I forgot to mention with all those verifications goes along with receipt validation which is done in back end server too.

Restore purchases: 
You have to provide this functionality otherwise your app will be cold rejected by Apple.

[**Here is the tutorial worth reading**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/147629/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscriptions-tutorial)

[**In-App Purchase FAQ**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html)